# Search feature on website

Tags: search, web

I am interested in implementing a search feature on a website. It is a location search, so address/state/zip all should work. Which will then show results in that area and allow it to be filtered.

My question is:
What's the best approach for something like this?

[image: search bar]

Comment: You need to be a LOT more specific with your question. What technology stack will the site be built in? PHP, .Net, something else?

Comment: @Tim that's mostly what the question is involving. I've never done a search option and was looking for an answer about what is typically used for something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are literally dozens of ways of doing this (if not more). The exact implementation would depend on the technology stack that you use, but as a very top level overview:

- you'd need to store the things you are searching for somewhere, and tag them with a lat/long location. Often, this would be in a database of some kind.
- using a programming language, you would need to write a search that accepts a postcode, translates that to a lat/long and then searches the things in your database based on the distance between the location of the thing, and the location entered in the search.
- if you want to support filtering, your search would need to support that too. This is often called "faceting" the search.

Working out the lat/long locations will need to be done using a GeoLocation service, there are some, such as PostCode Anywhere that will do this as a paid service, and others that are free (within reason), such as the Google Maps APIs.

There are probably some hosted services that will do what you want, you'd have to shop around.

Examples of search software that supports geolocation searching out of the box are things like Solr, Azure Search, Lucene and Elastic.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!